# Convert String to Array in JavaScript -- difficulty formatting alert

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to convert string into array and put them. I try an event click of button #bt_click. It prints an alert.

Example Code follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $("#bt_click").click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(string_to_array('Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|'));
        });

        function string_to_array(string_text)
        {
            var res = new Array();
            res =   string_text.split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
            {
               return res[i] +  '&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />';
            }
        } 

         });
```

Intended result of alert:

```
Jan  Feb  Mar  (line 1)
Apr  May  Jun  (line 2)
Jul  Aug  Sep   (line 3)
Oct  Nov  Dec   (line 4)
```

How can I format alert correctly. Thanks all.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
    function string_to_array(string_text){
        var res = new Array();
        var result='';
        res =   string_text.split("|");
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
        {
           result += res[i];
           result += (i%3===2)?'\n':'  ';
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your input string has an extra '|' at the end that's why it is creating a new line.

Comment: Sory, It seems that it does not seem right. It added one new line. I checked by adding the word "Date" before each element. and inform it wrong `code`  function string_to_array(string_text)
{
        var res = new Array();
        var result='';
        res =   string_text.split("|");
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
        {
           result += 'Date:'+res[i]+'---';
           result += (i%3===2)?'\n':'  ';
        }
        return result;
    } 
`code`
Result`code` Date:Jan---  Date:Feb---  Date:Mar---
...
Date:Oct---  Date:Nov---  Date:Dec---
Date:---  `code`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I did not get you. What you are expecting here ?

Actually split function create string to array with the character.

```
var str="Hello this is array string";

var strArray= str.split(" ");

In your case you can specify different character.

var str="Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|";

var strArray= str.split("|");
```

Or your function will work with some modifications. You will get first element only with the old code because you are returning the value from loop itself.

```
function string_to_array(string_text)
        {
            var res = "";

            res =   string_text.split("|");

            var formatedStrings="";

            for (var i = 1; i < (res.length)+1; i++)
            {
               formatedStrings=formatedStrings+'&nbsp;&nbsp;';

               if(i%3==0)
               {
                  formatedStrings=formatedStrings+'\n';
               }
            }

            return formatedStrings;
        }
```